# how to setup a local repo of mercurial

Tags: mercurial

here is the complete scenario:

1. Main repository: `http://10.0.1.8:8000/ptest`
2. I clone it at host `10.1.0.115`, in the folder `/LOCAL-REPO`
3. Then, publish it using the command `hg serve -p 9900 -d --webdir-conf hgwebconfig` with the `hgwebconfig` file having

   ```
   [paths]
   ptest = /LOCAL_REPO/ptest
   [web]
   style = gitweb
   ```

now, on the same host 10.0.1.115, i create a seperate folder `/QA` and do:

```
hg clone http://10.0.1.115:9900/ptest
```

and get all the files, now i want to make changes and *push* them to the repo on 
`http://10.0.1.115:9900/ptest` using the command

```
hg push ssh://10.0.1.115//??/ptest
```

I don't know what the correct value would be for `??`. So the questions are:

1. How do i setup a user/password to push changes to this repo on `10.0.1.115`?
2. what is the corect syntax in this case?

When I try to push the changes I get error:

```
hg push ssh://user@10.0.1.115/ptest
user@10.0.1.115's password: 
remote: abort: There is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to push via ssh:// when you pulled via http:// ?

After `hg clone http://10.0.1.115:9900/ptest` clone you should be able to push it via http as well, like `hg push http://10.0.1.115:9900/ptest`

But if you really need to push via ssh here it is: you must have your repository accessible under local account, e.g. if user is `hg` and it's homedir is `/home/hg` and you will have your repo in `/home/hg/repository` directory then you will be able to access it via command:

```
hg push ssh://hg@10.0.1.115/repository/
```

User/password will be same as to ssh onto user `hg`.

Comment: i can also do hg push ~/LOCAL_REPO/ptest/ , awesome!, Thanks @romke